# How to get all associated data with the salesforce account object in ruby on rails using restforce gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to fetch all the user data from the salesforce using restforce REST Api.I have salesforce account object. Now i would like to get all associated data with this account object.

Answer (score 3):

This is a multi-step process:

1. Get the columns for the object:

   ```
   # get the describe for the Account object
   account_columns = client.describe('Account')
   # => { ... }
   ```
2. Run a normal query:

   ```
   accounts = client.query("select #{account_columns} from Account where Id = 'someid'")
   # => #<Restforce::Collection>

   account = accounts.first
   # => #<Restforce::SObject>
   ```
3. Access related objects:

   ```
   account.Owner
   ```

Source - https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce